# Erro ao compilar projeto Android Studio com Gradle

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

Estou com um problema ao compilar meu projeto do Gradle.
Tenho a seguinte resposta do compilador:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':mobile:processBroadcastHomologDebugResources'.
        > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
        Process 'command '/media/leonardootto/data/work/tools/java/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.0/aapt'' 
        finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um problema com meu layout, apesar do compilar não informar nenhuma informação útil.

Tenho o seguinte layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cinza_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@id/rootLayout">

</LinearLayout>
```

Já tinha outro lugar com este id, então tive que trocar para:

```
<LinearLayout 
    ...
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```